# Represent record associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

All,

How can I show record association in the "view" part of the MVC using Rails? Ex. I have a class for `Building` which would have many `apartments` each with a single unique apartment number.

Since I am new to Rails, I wanted to understand what is generally the UI structure to represent such associations on the UI side.

Comment: can u elaborate? associations are at the model part of the MVC stack. What do u mean by the UI structure?

Comment: I meant how can I "express" the association on the UI? The scaffold would let me create, edit, delete `Building`, `Apartment` entries. But how can I associate multiple `Apartments` to a `Building`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not clear, this is how your models would look

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :building
end

class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :apartments
end
```

In your routes.rb you may want to have the following

```
resources :building do
 resources :apartments
end
```